# How to use javascript functions in an Angular 2 component from a different file

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a javascript file that contains some data manipulation functions (No DOM manipulation at all) such as float rounding, mathematical operations, ...etc

my js file called ***myexample.js*** looks like that

```
function example(input) {
  return input * 2
}
module.exports = { example: example }
```

and then I have my angular component ***example.component.ts***

for example:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'input-number',
  template: `<input 
              type='text' 
              [(value)]='value' 
              (blur)='runExample()' 
             />`,
  inputs: ['value'],
  outputs: ['valueChange']
})
export class Example {
  value: string;
  valueChange = new EventEmitter;

  runExample() {
    let val = parseFloat(this.value);
    // here i need to call example(input) from myexample.js
    // and assign the return to val
    this.valueChange.emit(val);
  }
```

I have been searching for quite a while now and tried multiple things but unfortunately with no luck at all.

I would be really grateful if someone can help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found out the answer; it was to basically make a typings file and add it to the project.

The problem was related to TypeScript not Angular2. In typeScript you can't simply use any JS file without having a definition (typing) file that declares the types of the vars, the params of the functions, as well as the returns. check [this link](https://peter.grman.at/how-to-write-typescript-definition-files/) to know how to create one.

Comment: How did you do that exactly?

Comment: Please explain the steps of the solution that you found.

Comment: The problem was related to TypeScript not Angular2. In typeScript you can't simply use any JS file without having a definition (typing) file that declares the types of the vars, the params of the functions, as well as the returns. check this link to know how to create one.  http://peter.grman.at/how-to-write-typescript-definition-files/

Answer (score 19):

You can export functions in TypeScript:

```
export function example(input) {
  return input * 2;
}
```

and use it this way (assuming your file name is lib.ts):

```
import {example} from './lib';

example();
```

If you want to use a CommonJS file, you need to configure SystemJS in the `map` attribute:

```
System.config({
  (...)
  map: {
    lib: 'path/to/lib/js'
  }
});
```

You can import your module the same way then:

```
import {example} from './lib';
```

Comment: 1- I have to use the javascript (can't convert it to typescript) file as it is shared between different projects

Comment: 2- what about if I am using webpack?

Comment: okay. Make sense... I think that you can require directly the file with Webpack. Something like `var lib = require('./path/to/lib');`

Comment: I imported it by `const lib = require('my/file/path')` and then from inside the component i called  `lib.example(input)` so now it is actually reading the file but I am getting this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: example is not defined` and the angular application is not running

Comment: If you use `console.log(lib)`, what is printed in the js console?

Comment: that's the thing, it doesn't reach it it fails from the start giving me that error

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to add your js functions defined in a separate file to a global scope. So in your js file you can add sth like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.example = example;
}
```

Then in your component typeScript file, right below the imports, you can declare this function:

```
declare function example(input): void;
```

And then you can just simply use this function in the component methods.

Answer (score 2):

this is what it worked for me
I was trying to use html2pdf from an Angular2 app, so I had to make a reference to this function

```
var html2pdf = (function(html2canvas, jsPDF) {
```

declared in html2pdf.js.

So I added just after the import declarations in my angular-controller this declaration:

```
declare function html2pdf(html2canvas, jsPDF): any;
```

then, from a method of my angular controller I'm calling this function:

```
generate_pdf(){
    this.someService.loadContent().subscribe(
      pdfContent => {
        html2pdf(pdfContent, {
          margin:       1,
          filename:     'myfile.pdf',
          image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
          html2canvas:  { dpi: 192, letterRendering: true },
          jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait' }
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Works for [this module](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) (it is not the only one named html2pdf)