# Angular 2 app doesnt load JS scripts in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular

I have some scripts in my html code in my angular 2 app and they do not load. When i check the console of the browser I do not see an attempt to even load the script? How can i load JS scripts in angular 2

```
div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                              setInterval(function() {
                                $('#element').load('/Resources/speedtest.txt');
                            }, 1000);
                        </script>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        <span id="element">Loading...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

There is an example of one of the scripts.. This is being used in a component called home and i use the template home.html where this is located.

here is the home component code.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.html'
})
export class homecomponent { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular just strips `<script>` tags from templates. You need other ways to load the script. For example using requirejs in your components code.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/12172

Comment: I had a feeling that was what was needed, so i basically need to put the js script in the export area of the component? Thank you very much as well!

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103920/how-to-use-javascript-functions-in-an-angular-2-component-from-a-different-file I haven't used it myself yet.

Comment: ahhhh ok thank you this information helps me alot i can find the answer from here! Your help is greatly appreciated thank you very much!