# Angular4 - Use a function inside a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, angular, import, referenceerror

I'm trying to load a JavaScript file into my angular component. I have loaded the full minified version from here: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/blob/master/js/load-image.all.min.js and also put any related scripts in my scripts folder.

When the code runs and reaches 'loadImage', the console fires an error:

> ERROR ReferenceError: loadImage is not defined

What's the best way to resolve this?

**Component**

```
import '../../../assets/scripts/load-image.all.min.js';
declare var loadImage: any;

...

dropChangeHandler(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   e = e.originalEvent
   var target = e.dataTransfer || e.target
   var file = target && target.files && target.files[0]

   var options = {
     maxWidth: 1000,
     maxHeight: 1000,
     canvas: true,
     pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,
     // downsamplingRatio: 0.5,
     orientation: true
   }
   if (!file) {
     return
   } else {

   this.currentFile = file;   
   if (!loadImage(file, this.updateResults, options)) {

   }

  }
}
```

I think this question is slightly different to the other 'import JS files into angular' because I have a feeling it might be to do with the library I'm trying to import. However, I'm unsure and seeking advice on this one.

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103920/how-to-use-javascript-functions-in-an-angular-2-component-from-a-different-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use javascript functions in an Angular 2 component from a different file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103920/how-to-use-javascript-functions-in-an-angular-2-component-from-a-different-file)

Answer (score 1):

The library you are trying to import doesn't support es6 modules. Because of no exports in the library, it doesn't add any variables to your scope after import.

In your particular case easiest is to add the script to index.html:

`<script src="assets/scripts/load-image.all.min.js"></script>`

and call a method in the component with

`window.loadImage(file, this.updateResult, options)`

*I use `window` because library directly binds itself to window.object*

---

**More details**

- To use javascript modules with typescript add `allowJs: true` to `tsconfig.js` file.
- `import './file` is known as an import for side-effects only and don't change the scope of the module, but can access to global app scope. It can help you in case you want to extend already imported module.
- You could import js module different ways:

  - For CommonJs modules it's possible to use `import * as ModuleName from './modulePath.js';` in your component.ts file and call as `ModuleName.exportedMethod()`.
  - to the Angular pipeline to be sure it is loaded with the module which
    imports it. If you are using angular cli, simply include it to you
    angular-cli.json in the section apps/scripts:

    ```
    {
      "apps":
         ...
         "scripts": [
             "assets/scripts/load-image.all.min.js"
         ]
    }
    ```
  - If you don't use angular-cli, you can include to your `index.html`:
    `<script src="assets/scripts/load-image.all.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know you could do that. A couple of things happened when I changed to the above. Visual Code states that file was "resolved from '...' to '..' but '--allowJs' is not set." - It compiles anyway. In the browser I run the code and now get "LoadImage.loadImage is not a function" - Am I missing anything obvious here? To clarify, I removed any reference in the angular-cli.json file and have just implemented the above. Thanks again Eugene!

Comment: I've just seen your updated comment. I removed the component import and added the script to the angular cli file. Is that correct? Or do I need both? If I have both it fails to compile. If I have the reference just in angular-cli, how do I call it in the component file? Appreciate your time! :)

Comment: You are right, thanks for correcting! You can import it only one way, not both. I will correct the answer.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I'm a little confused as to what's happening. If I include the script in either the index file, or angular-cli, the browser console will throw the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". However, if I import the file into my component.ts file (not the module), and then reference the function as Loadimage.loadImage, it states that "LoadImage.loadImage is not a function". Any ideas?

Comment: That's good you add `--allowJs` to your tsconf.
I just realised that your library just doesn't use any value to export and bind loadImage function directly to window object.

Comment: Thanks. Yup, I fixed the `--allowJs` part, thanks! - Ok in regards to the rest, any suggestions? The scripts work perfectly fine in code pen etc as a demo. It's just integrating it into angular is proving to be a real pain in the ass.

Comment: In your case it would be possible to use the library by adding in to `angular-cli.json` as you already did, set `"allowJs": true` in `tsconfig.js` andd finally using it in your module as `window.loadImage`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171772/discussion-between-etx-and-eugene-gavrilov).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to export the wanted function in your imported file.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse Bernd. Apologies. New to this. Are you referring to the 'load-image.all.min.js' file? If so, how do you set up an export?

Answer (score 0):

you must unsusure that the library is will be compiled
Add the script in **angular-cli.json**

```
"scripts": [
....
'<path to file>/assets/scripts/load-image.all.min.js'
....
]
```

then

```
declare var loadImage: any;
```

Comment: Thanks Segito - I also tried this. The solution compiles, but the browser console reads 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'